# Natural language processing in java for sort out good and bad comment from DB

Tags: nlp, gate

I've some bunch of Comments/User-reviews in my DB of some particular products, say Samsung android phones. Now I want sort-out those comments, whether it is a good comment or bad comment. I gone through GATE(General Architecture for Text Engineering), but I dint get any examples to sort out comments. I got other examples like ANNIE, Golden-fish etc., Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks:
Ramakrishna K.C

Answer (score 0):

Do you need [sentiment analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis)?

If so, you can try one of the available services, for instance [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/). They provide document sentiment score among the other things.

Comment: yup. I seen this. It is good. But, I want to implement in my java App. Can you please suggest me how to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try the text classification approach:

First of all, make sure to annotate a bunch of comments according to what you consider good or bad. You will need at least 100, but the more the better.

Then use a text classification library like this one, for example: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/libshorttext.html

Comment: Is there any good java example for this? In that, they given for python right?

Comment: You could use Mallet if you want to work in Java: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/classification.php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to GATE Training Courses materials: http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/ . There you will find a brief approach of Sentiments Analysis using GATE platform.(http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseAug2010/ Track 3 if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I referred [link]https://gate.ac.uk/sentiment/.Actually I want java coding part to implement/fit in project(example of sentiment). I run this [link]https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java But, It's giving run time exception

Exception in thread "main" gate.util.GateRuntimeException: Could not infer installed plug-ins home!
Please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script.
 at gate.Gate.initLocalPaths(Gate.java:316)
 at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:163)
 at sheffield.examples.StandAloneAnnie.main(StandAloneAnnie.java:85)

Comment: I set System property and all correctly. If you don't mind can you please check that example? Now, I'm running all required lib with StandAloneAnnie.java class. I don't know where I've to set manually "-Dgate.plugins.home"

Comment: Guess  you can have a look to my old blog: http://blog.langbricks.com/2010/06/18/structure-of-the-gate-framework-in-the-web-and-standalone-applications.aspx . There you can find some ideas of how to use GATE in standalone application.

Comment: Blog contains nice explanation. I did exactly what it says. Still I'm getting same exception that "Please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script". I'm not using in web-App. The Annie program in a simple-java application. I've gate.xml configuration."<GATE>
<GATECONFIG Save_options_on_exit="true" Save_session_on_exit="true"/>
</GATE>" & creole.xml with configuration "<GATE>
    <GATECONFIG Known_plugin_path="gate.plugins.home" Load_plugin_path="C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_7.1\plugins"/>
</GATE>" with all libraries. Please see my configuration & help me.

Comment: Sorry, have not seen your response. Is this still actual issue?

Comment: Yup. Completely struck in Sentimental analysis process in java. I don't know what to do.